# I ran an optional update for windows. I pushed the restart now button. I have been waiting for the restart for 48 hours

Tags: windows, windows-10

I ran an optional update for Windows 10.

I pushed the restart now button (on the Windows 10 Update Screen). I have been waiting for the restart for 48 hours, but a restart has not occurred.

The screen remains black.

Blue light blinks on and off. I can’t get to settings or anything else and the machine is stuck in restart mode after windows update.

Question:  How do I proceed?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “restart mode”? Please [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

Answer (score 2):

> I ran an optional update for windows. I pushed the restart now button.
> I have been waiting for the restart for 48 hours. Screen is black

If it has not restarted after 2 days, it will not restart on its own

Turn the computer OFF (power button), wait a minute or two, and then start up

It will pick up where it left off and either complete the update or roll back the update.

If the update rolled back, try again and make sure the update is for your particular machine.

Comment: Alternatively, when it's obvious that the reboot is stuck, press CTRL+ALT+DEL.  I have one laptop that failed to reboot after Windows 10 updates routinely for months.  CAD always got it running again. Early on, it'd back out the update, later, it'd just start, and praise Baud, lately it just restarts on its own w/o intervention.